# creating c++ queue with more than one datatype?

Tags: c++

I thought I was doing this right but it doesn't seem to be working.  I'm basically experimenting with a queue and it works fine with one data type but now I'm trying to add multiple(in the end I want to have a int and a list of ints).

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    struct product {
      int x;
      int y;
    } ;


   queue<product> q;
   q.push(100, 100);
   q.push(200, 100);
   q.push(300, 100);
   q.push(400, 100);

   cout << "Size of the queue: " << q.size() << endl;

   while (!q.empty()) {
       cout << q.front() << endl;
       q.pop();
   }

}
```

It works without the struct, but obviously it only accepts one variable for each item in the queue that way.  Is there a way to have multiple items?

Comment: Your question is unclear.  What do you mean by adding multiple items?

Comment: @Attila I would like a queue with multiple datatypes per queue item. So in this example, each item of the queue has two ints.

Comment: You can't have a `queue` with more than one datatype, but you can have a `queue` of say variants over several datatypes. Look for Boost.Variant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* the type specified for the template type cannot be a local definition. Change to:

```
struct product {
  int x;
  int y;
} ;

int main()
{
```

As others have already stated, add a constructor to `product` that accepts both arguments:

```
struct product {
    int x;
    int y;
    product(int a_x, int a_y) : x(a_x), y(a_y) {}
};

...

q.push_back(product(100, 100));
```

You could also overload `operator<<` for outputting a `product`:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& a_out, const product& a_p)
{
    a_out << "product(" << a_p.x << ", " << a_p.y << ")";
    return a_out;
}

while (!q.empty()) {
    cout << q.front() << endl;
    q.pop();
}
```

Comment: And the constructor thing the others said.

Comment: Interestingly, the local type can be defined as a template parameter at the least in VS 2010. The code I wrote as an answer works fine with VS 2010.

Comment: @Jaywalker, really? That is what I checked with (plus g++), but I compiled with extensions disabled (`/Za` compiler flag).

Answer (score 2):

The `queue::push` method expects one parameter, which must be of the type of your queue. Try it like this:

```
queue<product> q;
q.push(product(100, 100));
q.push(product(200, 100));
q.push(product(300, 100));
q.push(product(400, 100));
```

You'd also have to define a constructor for your struct:

```
struct product {
  int x;
  int y;
  product(int _x, int _y) : x(_x), y(_y) {}
} ;
```

Comment: I see get the same error(your approach is the same as Jaywalker's). and if I use your constructor or his, I still get the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how your main should look like. Note the addition of the constructor `product(int i, int j)`, and the use of the constructor in adding elements to `q`.

```
int main ()
{
    struct product {
      int x;
      int y;

      product (int i, int j) : x(i), y(j) {}
    } ;

   queue<product> q;
   q.push(product (100, 100));
   q.push(product (200, 100));
   q.push(product (300, 100));
   q.push(product (400, 100));

   cout << "Size of the queue: " << q.size() << endl;

   while (!q.empty()) {
       cout << q.front().x << ", " << q.front().y << endl;
       q.pop();
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for me.  I get a bunch of errors. template arguement invalid, invalid type in declaration before ';', etc..

Comment: the first 4 errors seem to be related to the line `queue<product> q;`

Comment: hmjd's answer and yours did it. I was missing the constructor and it couldn't be locally declared..

Answer (score 1):

`q.push(100, 100)` is invalid, `queue::push()` takes only one parameter.  You will need to push a `product` instead:

```
product p(100, 100);
q.push(p);
```

Then you have both 100s in the queue (stored in the product stucture).

If you want to store both a `product1` and a `product2`, you will need a common base structure that both extends and store pointers (to the base) instead of the values themselves (to avoud slicing).  At this point you might as well use `class` instead of `struct`